# Search and replacing strings in a numerical data file

Tags: awk, grep, search

I have a data file I need to edit it is in the form:

```
-8.915602898150751e-05-7.050591991128022e-05-4.361255125222242e-052.309505585477205e-05-2.223040239244275e-051.088544645124330e-011.000000000000000e-15
7.528375184423486e-062.558479420795495e-052.537280868441473e-04-5.119189471594489e-056.455268837875294e-054.463628820267331e-011.000000000000000e-15
```

As you can the numbers have no spaces and I would like to edit the file in a very specific manner (I will be using it as an input file for simulation work). I would like the file to look like:

```
 -1.0000000000000001e-001  0.0000000000000000e+000  0.0000000000000000e+000  4.3052618410549812e+009  0.0000000000000000e+000  0.0000000000000000e+000  2.4853118072193338e-015
  2.4106903033391415e-004  4.3586744793222273e-005  4.5561759893187341e-005 -4.0315591956328645e+007 -9.1758824977759705e+003 -2.5181138417225957e+004  2.4853118072193338e-015
```

I have developed an algorithm to do such an edit and tried it in Notepad++ but, the programs adds "invisible" characters to the file which makes it invalid for my simulation. Here is the algorithm:

1. find string "-1." and replace with string " -1." (there is one space in front of the negative sign in the replacement)
2. Repeat step 1 for numbers 2-9.
3. find string "1." and replace with string "  1." (there are two spaces in front of the 1 in the replacement)
4. Repeat step 3 for numbers 2-9.
5. find string "-  1." and replace with "-1." (there are two spaces between the negative sign and 1 in the find string)
6. Repeat step 5 for numbers 2-9.

I want to do this in a UNIX shell (I am using macbook terminal) as I believe this will not add invisible characters and corrupt my data. Any help guys?

Thanks in advance!!!!!

Comment: There should be two spaces between the numbers unless it has a negative sign, then only one space as such: -4.361255125222242e-05  2.309505585477205e-05

Comment: Your expected output doesn't match your input

Comment: Hmmmm may be an issue with my algorithm. Any suggestions?

Comment: Would `sed -E 's/[0-9.-]*e-?[0-9]{2}/ &/g'` do?

Comment: Hi Stephane, where would I include my input file in that command line? For example "data.txt"

Comment: `sed -E 's/[0-9.+-]*e[-+]?[0-9]{2}/ &/g' data.txt` or `sed -E 's/[0-9.+-]*e[-+]?[0-9]{2}/ &/g' < data.txt`. See also `sed -E 's/e[-+]?[0-9]{2}/& /g' data.txt`

Comment: `sed 's/-\?[0-9]\./ &/g;s/ [0-9]\./ &/g' data.txt`

Comment: That does a good job in separating the numbers but it does not leave them in clean column form. The numbers are all staggered which unfortunately, wont work in my simulation :(

Comment: With Stéphane Chazelas work: `printf " %22s %22s %22s %22s %22s %22s %22s\n" $(sed -E 's/e[-+]?[0-9]{2}/& /g' data.txt)`

Comment: Costas, that command line didnt seem to do anything to the file? The output was exactly the same

Comment: @user111843: Costas version works fine for me with GNU sed.

Comment: Excellent Cyrus. Thank you SO much. That worked perfectly. Hmmm, interesting I do not know why Costas version did not work for me :(

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -E '
   s/[0-9.+-]*e[-+]?[0-9]{2}/     &/g
   s/ *(.{22}[0-9])/\1/g' < input.txt > output.txt
```

That assumes GNU or FreeBSD (or derivative like OS/X) `sed`, or a `sed` conformant to the next version of the Unix/POSIX standard (for `-E`).